# rp2040 DMA channel hung, baremetal

Tags: dma, bare-metal, rp2040

I'm trying to trigger a DMA channel to perform a memory-to-memory transfer within the SRAM. The channel throws up the busy flag, but there is no change to the transfer count.

I have the following code:

```
    ;reset dma
    ldr r0, *resets_clr ;clear reset
    mov r1, 4
    str r1, (r0, 0)
    
    ldr r0, *resets_rw ;confirm reset clear
*rst_dma
    ldr r2, (r0, 2)
    and r2, r1
    beq *rst_dma
    
    ;start dma channel
    ldr r0, *dma_rw
    adr r1, *var
    str r1, (r0, 0) ;read addr
    
    ldr r1, *sram_addr
    str r1, (r0, 1) ;write addr
    
    mov r1, 8
    str r1, (r0, 2) ;trans count
    
    mov r1, 47 ;incr_write | size_word | high_priority | en
    str r1, (r0, 3) ;ctrl trig
    
    ;wait for transfer marked complete
    mov r2, 1
    lsl r2, r2, 24
*busy_dma
    ldr r1, (r0, 3)
    and r1, r2
    bne *busy_dma
    
    ;test
    ldr r0, *sram_addr
    ldr r1, (r0, 0)
    mov lr, pc
    cmp r1, 7
    beq  *led_on
```

With the following word-sized values:

```
resets_rw 0x4000c000

resets_clr 0x4000f000

var 7

dma_rw 0x50000000

sram_addr 0x20001000
```

The chip hangs up in the `rst_dma` loop, which waits until the channel drops its busy flag. If I run without the loop, the memory test fails. The channel throws no AHB error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already typed the question out so might as well answer it.

The channel control register has a field to select a transfer request signal (`TREQ_SEL`), which resets to the first data request channel,  `DREQ_PIO0_TX0`. If you're not using the DMA with a peripheral, and don't care about timing the transfer pace, you should set the field to `0x3f` for unpaced transfers.

```
    mov r1, 63 ;treq_sel unpaced transfer
    lsl r1, r1, 15
    add r1, 47 ;inc_write | size_word | en
    str r1, (r0, 3) ;ctrl trig
```

Without this, the DMA will just sit there, waiting for a non-existent signal.